# SceneKit – Apply a Force in the Direction of SCNNode is facing

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have an ARKit application where I have a car model. I want to apply force to the car the direction car is facing.

```
func accelerate() {           
    // force should be applied in the direction.
    let force = SCNVector3(0,0,-1)
    self.physicsBody?.applyForce(force, asImpulse: true)
}

func turnRight() {
    self.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(0,1.0,0,-0.1), asImpulse: true)
}

func turnLeft() {      
    self.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(0,1.0,0,0.1), asImpulse: true)
}
```

The accelerate function is the one I need to implement so I can apply the force in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an invisible node in front of the car as a child of the car. That way it will not move and you will always have a point of reference in front of the car.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for moving forward:

```
node.physicsBody?.velocity += force
```